# Unchosen a chosen jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code..

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#staffs').chosen();
             $('#region').chosen();
             $('#province').chosen();
});
```

I want to make it dynamic in a sense that when the region is changed it will change the dropdown in the province. How to unchosen the province select box?

Answer (score 2):

You can check documentation [here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events)

If your select content changed you should use `$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");` function.